# css for "all available width"?

Tags: css

How can I specify that the width of a given element should be the "maximum available width", once its horizontal margins, its parent's horizontal padding, etc. are taken into account, and also assuming that the parent's width has not been specified explicitly?

BTW, contrary to what one may think, `width:100%` is *decidedly not* the answer to this question (see [here](http://www.impressivewebs.com/width-100-percent-css/), for example).

(There are many questions on SO that seem to ask the same thing as this one, but on closer inspection one finds that those are far more specific than this one, and their answers depend on very specific details of some code presented in the question.  Here I'm looking for as general as possible an answer.)

Comment: You can either use javascript, tables or [flex-boxs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes). Choose your poison

Comment: @megawac: "poison" is the right word, indeed...  JS sounds particularly painful, as poisons go: one would have to compute the available width "by hand", so to speak.  This means taking into account all the paddings, margins, borders, etc., plus the width of other "relevant" elements within the same container, etc., etc.  Ugh.

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box`? it changes the layout so width and height include everything but margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fairly Easily

What you describe is the default behavior of anything that is `display: block`. So [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fJb35/1/) shows a "normal" layout for some mixed `inline` and `block` elements contrasted to all those elements simply set to `display: block`.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can add `display: table;` to the `parent`.
The childrens will always fill `100%` of the parent element.

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nSR86/1/) that I put together for you.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for me.  For example, in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xVzY2/), you can see that some of the `label` elements fail to extend to the width of the enclosing `td` element; if I try your solution ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fJb35/)) then the formatting goes all out of whack...